# haproxy goes fishing

Tags: haproxy

I am using haproxy to direct the traffic to port A to a service running on port B. When the service is down, I want to make haproxy go to a fishing page immediately. I went over the haproxy documents, but have not been able to find how I can achieve this. Can someone shed a light on my problem? thanks!

Comment: I think I might need to clarify my questions. Is it possible that we make haproxy totally skewed? It means haproxy will forward traffic to server B ONLY if server A dies.

Answer (score 5):

This question is pretty old but maybe someone will find the answer useful. It sounds like you're looking for the "backup" option:

*When "backup" is present on a server line, the server is only used in load balancing when all other non-backup servers are unavailable.*

Ref: http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/ServerOptions

A config line for a local apache instance serving an "Oops" page might look something like this:

server localhost 127.0.0.1:80 backup